# Can I Simulate a SMPS Compensator on Matlab/Simulink

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, simulation, matlab, simulink

I've designed a type 3 compensator for a full bridge dc-dc converter, I just want to be sure about its stability and want to check its bode plots, I have a open loop model, I can apply pi control on it but the real circuit I have has an analog control and I need to check its stability is there any way that I can simulate a type 3 compensator on matlab/simulink environment.

Comment: I expect that there is but details will be needed.

Comment: What do you mean with details? Detailed component modelling? @Andyaka

Comment: Well, so far, the only answer your question permits is "I expect so".

Comment: Simulink has transfer function and gain blocks which can be used to construct the type three compensator you designed. The open loop model can also likely be modelled in simulink. Once both are modelled you can check the stability.

Comment: If you have the plant transfer function \$H(s)\$ and you can plot it in Matlab, then simply write the transfer function \$G(s)\$ of the type 3 compensator (1 pole at the origin, two poles and two zeroes) and plot \$T(s)=H(s)G(s\$ and there you go.

Comment: Yes it can. How much information do you have

Comment: @JonRB information about matlab or compensation?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link below the question to add more details about the plant, its model as well as the designed compensator and whatever you have already done in matlab for the above plant and compensator. The question is very vague in its current state.

Answer (score 0):

It's very much possible and encouraged to do this. Since you have the values of your capacitors and resistors, you can write the transfer function of it and replace the variables of capacitors and resistors. Then you can use the bode plot function from Matlab with said transfer function.

However, if you're wanting to also include values of parasitics and whatnot the transfer function becomes more complex and you'll need a circuit simulator instead. But for a first pass and ballpark estimate of where the poles and zeros of you compensator are you can ignore parasitics.